# Read Excel in Spark Error :InputStream of class ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics

Tags: excel, apache-spark, spark-excel

I am trying to read excel files from COS via spark , like this

```
    def readExcelData(filePath: String, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame =
        spark.read
          .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
          .option("path", filePath)
          .option("useHeader", "true")
          .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
          .option("inferSchema", "False")
          .option("addColorColumns", "False")
          .load()
  def readAllFiles: DataFrame = {
      val objLst //contains  the list the file paths
      val schema = StructType(
          StructField("col1", StringType, true) ::
            StructField("col2", StringType, true) ::
            StructField("col3", StringType, true) ::
            StructField("col4", StringType, true) :: Nil
        )
      var initialDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema)
        for (file <- objLst) {
          initialDF = initialDF.union(
            readExcelData(file, spark).select($"col1", $"col2", $"col3", $"col4"))
        }
}
```

In this code , I am creating an empty dataframe first , then reading all the excel files (by iterating the filepaths ) and merging the data via a union operation.

It is throwing an error like this

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.<init>(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:63)
```

The sparkExcel version is 0.10.2

Answer (score 0):

try removing the .show() for your original statement and convert to dataframe first.

```
def readExcel(file: String): DataFrame = spark.read
        .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
        .option("useHeader", "true")
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "False")
        .option("addColorColumns", "False")
        .load()
val data = readExcel("path to your excel file")

data.show()
```

Comment: @AyanBiswas I removed the .option(path) can you put the path in the readexcel and try it again?

Comment: without option(path) it throws an error. so I had already added that option